# How to Validate a json having several line and para breaks?

Tags: json

Sample:

```
{"text": " abc

def

ghi

jkl
mk

opqr

stuv" }
```

Can this be validated without removing breaks.

Comment: Your comment on my answer makes me think the question is unclear. Please add details to clarify what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not allow line breaks in strings. They have to be replaced with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Used jsoneditoronline and it escaped it using /n or /r/n. Then validated json was obtained.  On mobile screen it gave the needed line break between texts. Used nested table features of ms word for merging columns having json format {"text":"..."}, as excel was bifurcating devnagiri.

Answer (score -2):

> Can this be validated without removing breaks.

Yes, it can. The validation result would be: It's invalid. :-) [JSON](https://json.org/) doesn't allow unescaped newlines in string literals.

If you want to check whether it's valid **other than** the invalid line breaks, but without removing them, I very much doubt you'll be able to without writing your own JSON validator (probably by forking an existing one and modifying it, there are several listed on the [json.org](https://json.org/) website).

You could *replace* them, converting carriage returns `\r` escape sequences and newlines to `\n` escape sequences using string replacement, but it seems like that would break your restriction against removing the line breaks.

In JavaScript, that would be:

```
json = json.replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
// or
json = json.replace(/[\r\n]/g, m => m === "\r" ? "\\r" : "\\n");
```

or similar.

Comment: On the mobile screen, i want the text to be displayed with line breaks i.e. as showed in question     How to achieve that ?

Comment: @MackyMac - What are you showing on the mobile screen, the JSON or the text it defines? If you're showing the JSON, you can't have standard newlines in it. If you're showing the text it defines, just put `\r` (for a carriage return) or `\n` (for a new line) where you want the line breaks. But you shouldn't have to do that manually. Never build JSON manually when you can avoid it. Build a structure in memory, and then use a JSON serializer to create the JSON.

Comment: @MackyMac - If you want apparent line breaks in the actual JSON, there's a hack you can use, but I wouldn't: The characters [U+2028](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2028) ("LINE SEPARATOR") and [U+2029](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2029) ("PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR") are both valid within JSON string literals. If whatever is rendering what you're showing on the mobile screen understands them correctly (many don't), you could show the JSON with those. But I assume you don't really need to show the **JSON**, just the text it defines, so see the comment  above. :-)